# Slick JS - Right Border on slides not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

If there is border added to the slides, then the *last slide* in the track *doesn't show the right border*.
This JS Fiddle shows this exact behavior. The last slide doesn't have any right borders.

[The JS Fiddle shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/2p56z308/7/)

HTML:

```
<section class="slider">
  <div class="x">slide1</div>
  <div class="x">slide2</div>
  <div class="x">slide3</div>
  <div class="x">slide4</div>
  <div class="x">slide5</div>
  <div class="x">slide6</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;

.slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: #e84a69;
}

.x {
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

JS (Just the SlickJS part):

```
$(".slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    arrows: false    
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.slider .x` class uses `width: 100%;` and you also have applied a 2px border, that means the total width is the equivalent of `100% + 2px`.

You can apply `box-sizing: border-box;` property to your `.slider .x` styles. This will take into account padding and borders in the total width. [Read more here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: However, your current code may still cut off some of the last border, as the slider width isn't always going to be a multiple of 4 (the number of slides). e.g. slider width of 99px will have slides of 25px width. 25x4 is 100px, leading to 1px being off-slider

Comment: hmm.. I was hoping that I might have missed some settings or something. But, sounds like code editing it is going to be after all.

Comment: be sure to apply `box-sizing: border-box;` too, otherwise there will still be some border off-slider

Comment: Yup! That actually didn't help. But I am going to patch the library for myself.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug of the plugin which rounds up the width of each slide. When the width of the container is not exactly divisible by the shown slides it will cause this problem.

See [Issue #2167: Slide width incorrect with slides to show greater than 2](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2167)

A workaround is offered, but you need to alter the plugin code to remove the rounding.

Comment: I don't mind the code altering bit. I will check out the link right away. Appreciate it.

Comment: Your answer and the next guys answer are pretty much same except for the link. That guy has lower votes. So, I am accepting his. Please don't mind this. And I really appreciate your help man!